# How can I access a global pointer outside of a C function?

Tags: c

I am trying to access the data of`*tkn` within a different function in my program for example: `putchar(*tkn);` It is a global variable but its not working correctly. Any ideas?

```
#define MAX 20
// globals
char *tkn;
char array[MAX];
...


void tokenize()
{

int i = 0, j = 0;
char *delim = " ";


tkn = strtok (str," ");         // get token 1
if (tkn != NULL) {
    printf("token1: ");

    while ((*tkn != 0) && (tkn != NULL))
    {
        putchar(*tkn);
        array[i] = *tkn;
        *tkn++;
        i++;
    }
   }                
}
```

Comment: There is no `tkn2` in the above code. Also: What is "Not working correctly"? What is the behavior you are expecting? What is actually happening?

Comment: whoops, that was supposed to be 'tkn'

Comment: Assuming you have `str` defined somewhere that we can't see and it isn't NULL, it should work correctly as far as I can see.  However, it would be more helpful to explain what is happening as well as explaining what you expect.

Comment: Yes I have str defined previously also. I am just parsing a string into tokens and then wanting to reference each token separately and do something with each.

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
    while ((*tkn != 0) && (tkn != NULL))
```

you need to reverse the conditions.  If `tkn` is a null pointer, you will crash when the first term is evaluated.  If you need to check a pointer for validity, do so before dereferencing it.

```
    while (tkn != NULL && *tkn != '\0')
```

The extra parentheses you added do no harm but are not necessary.  And although `0` is a perfectly good zero, the `'\0'` emphasizes that `*tkn` is a character.  Of course, given the prior `tkn != NULL` condition in the if statement, there is no real need to repeat the check in the while loop.

---

Working code based on yours - some work left to do for subsequent tokens in the string, for example...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAX = 20 };
char *tkn;
char array[MAX];
char str[2*MAX];

void tokenize(void)
{
    int i = 0;

    array[0] = '\0';

    tkn = strtok(str, " ");         // get token 1
    if (tkn != NULL)
    {
        printf("token1: ");
        while (tkn != NULL && *tkn != '\0' && i < MAX - 1)
        {
            putchar(*tkn);
            array[i++] = *tkn++;
        }
        *tkn = '\0';
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    strcpy(str, "abc def");
    tokenize();
    printf("token = <<%s>>\n", array);
    strcpy(str, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    tokenize();
    printf("token = <<%s>>\n", array);
    return(0);
}
```

Sample output:

```
token1: abc
token = <<abc>>
token1: abcdefghijklmnopqrs
token = <<abcdefghijklmnopqrs>>
```

---

Asked:

> But what if I am taking in a string 'abc 3fc ghi' and I want to use just '3fc' in another function that say converts it from ascii to hex? How do I just use say tkn2 for 3fc and get that only using a pointer? – patrick 9 mins ago

That's where it gets trickier because `strtok()` has a moderately fiendish interface.

Leaving `tokenize()` unchanged, let's redefine `str`:

```
char *str;
```

Then, we can use (untested):

```
int main(void)
{
    char buffer[2*MAX];
    strcpy(buffer, "abc 3fc ghi");
    str = buffer;
    tokenize();
    printf("token = <<%s>>\n", array); // "abc"
    str = NULL;
    tokenize();
    printf("token = <<%s>>\n", array); // "3fc"
    str = NULL;
    tokenize();
    printf("token = <<%s>>\n", array); // "ghi"
    return(0);
}
```

Clearly, this relies on knowing that there are three tokens.  To generalize, you'd need the tokenizer to tell you when there's nothing left to tokenize.

Note that having `tkn` as a global is really unnecessary - indeed, you should aim to avoid globals as much as possible.

Comment: But what if I am taking in a string 'abc 3fc ghi' and I want to use just '3fc' in another function that say converts it from ascii to hex? How do I just use say tkn2 for 3fc and get that only using a pointer?

Answer (score 1):

You should use

tkn++

rather than

*tkn++

Comment: It's in the static storage within `strtok(3)`.

Comment: Nikolai: No it's not, it's within the string originally pointed to by `str`.

Comment: @ziang: both versions of this post are more appropriate as comments (or as a note at the end of another answer) than as answers, since they deal with issues outside of what the question is concerned with.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`strlcpy(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlcpy) instead of hand-coding the copy (hint - you are forgetting string zero terminator):

```
strlcpy( array, tkn, MAX );
```

Comment: Be careful what you recommend.  strlcpy(3) isn't defined in ISO C or ISO C++, so it isn't necessarily available for use in all environments (especially in the case of Windows where it isn't available at all).

Comment: I am careful :) I'm pushing the kids into right(tm) direction!

Answer (score 0):

Although `tkn` itself is a global variable, you also have to make sure that *what it points to* (ie. `*tkn`) is still around when you try to use it.

When you set `tkn` with a line like:

```
tkn = strtok (str," ");
```

Then `tkn` is pointing to part of the string that `str` points to.  So if `str` was pointing to a non-static array declared in a function, for example, and that function has exited - then `*tkn` isn't allowed any more.  If `str` was pointing to a block of memory allocated by `malloc()`, and you've called `free()` on that memory - then accessing `*tkn` isn't allowed after that point.